# Eloquent query gets no result, but on database it works

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Laravel gets no result for this function:

```
 public function freigabenabruf()
 {
   DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
   $freigaben=DB::table('freigaben AS fg')
   ->join('TFI_RECHNUNG AS re', 're.re_nr_intern', 'fg.re_nr_intern')
   ->select( 'fg.freigabe1', 'fg.freigabe2', 'fg.created_at', 'fg.updated_at')
   ->orderBy('fg.created_at', 'desc')
   ->get();
    var_dump($freigaben);
     dd(DB::getQueryLog());
     return $freigaben;
 }
```

QueryLog retrieves:

```
   object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#293 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } } 
    array:1 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "query" => "select "FG"."FREIGABE1", "FG"."FREIGABE2", "FG"."CREATED_AT", "FG"."UPDATED_AT" from "FREIGABEN" fg inner join "TFI_RECHNUNG" re on "RE"."RE_NR_INTERN" = "FG"." ▶"
        "bindings" => []
        "time" => 7.76
      ]
    ]
```

When I execute the query on database, I get my expected results...

Whats wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: Problem solved... Next time I should commit my inserts before I create a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `select()` two times. Try by using single `select()`

```
$freigaben=DB::table('freigaben AS fg')
   ->join('TFI_RECHNUNG AS re', 're.re_nr_intern', 'fg.re_nr_intern')
   ->select('re_nr', 'freigabe1', 'freigabe2', 'created_at', 'updated_at','fg.freigabe1', 'fg.freigabe2', 'fg.created_at', 'fg.updated_at')
   ->orderBy('fg.created_at', 'desc')
   ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but there is no advance.